# React render button 'x' of times

Tags: reactjs

I have a **switch button** that I want to copy ten times but when I copy the button to new **div** it does not let me click on second button onwards, I can change state of one first button only. Here is my code

```
class App extends Component {
  handleSwitch = e => console.log(e.target.checked);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p className="title">source</p>
          <label className="label">Button</label>2
          <SwitchButton
            onChange={this.handleSwitch}
            title="SwitchButton"
            data-name="vd"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className="label">Button2</label>
          <SwitchButton
            onChange={this.handleSwitch}
            title="SwitchButton2"
            data-name="vd1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is my live demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9n4lwa?file=index.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a unique switchButtonID in each SwitchButton

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import SwitchButton from './Hello';
import './style.scss';
class App extends Component {
  handleSwitch = e => console.log(e.target.checked);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p className="title">Precursor source</p>
          <label className="label">Ch1_PulsingValveActivationlnSw</label>
          <SwitchButton
            switchButtonID={1}
            onChange={this.handleSwitch}
            title="SwitchButton"
            data-name="vd"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className="label">Ch1_PulsingValveActivationlnSw</label>
          <SwitchButton
            switchButtonID={2}
            onChange={this.handleSwitch}
            title="SwitchButton2"
            data-name="vd1"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```